# Quickblox not delivering GCM notifications immediately

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, quickblox

QuickBlox not delivering GCM notifications to subscribed devices. I tried sending notification message from Admin Panel too, but it isn't delivered to device, but still in Admin Panel it shows it as "sent". But no history available.

And also what could be the reason for this ? How to mitigate this ?

How to view sent GCM notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The admin panel is not good enough - it lies sometime by saying 'send successfully' but it never reaches the other end.
Try sending the GCM notification by using the code snippet provided in the documentation. It works always.

```
public void sendMessageOnClick() {
    // Send Push: create QuickBlox Push Notification Event
    QBEvent qbEvent = new QBEvent();
    qbEvent.setNotificationType(QBNotificationType.PUSH);
    qbEvent.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT);

    // generic push - will be delivered to all platforms (Android, iOS, WP, Blackberry..)
    qbEvent.setMessage("how are you doing");

    StringifyArrayList<Integer> userIds = new StringifyArrayList<Integer>();
    userIds.add(6132691);
    qbEvent.setUserIds(userIds);


    QBMessages.createEvent(qbEvent, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBEvent qbEvent, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> strings) {
            // errors

        }
    });


}
```

//OR the below:--

```
private void sendPushNotifications(){

    // recipients
    StringifyArrayList<Integer> userIds = new StringifyArrayList<Integer>();
    userIds.add(6114793);
    //userIds.add(960);

    QBEvent event = new QBEvent();
    event.setUserIds(userIds);
    event.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT);
    event.setNotificationType(QBNotificationType.PUSH);
    event.setPushType(QBPushType.GCM);
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("data.message", "Hello");
    data.put("data.type", "welcome message");
    event.setMessage(data);

    QBMessages.createEvent(event, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBEvent qbEvent, Bundle args) {
            // sent
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {

        }
    });

}
```